# Ajax request to controller getting redirected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I encountered some weird behaviour when using an ajax request to get a response from a rails controller action.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/notifications'
});
```

```ruby
def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, alert: 'Page not accessible' }
        format.js
    end
end
```

So this respond_to block works fine when using requests with rails' `remote: true` option, but with the ajax call it just redirects the request to `root_url`.

Is the ajax request in a different format than `js`?

---

Even specifying `dataType: 'text/javascript',` in the ajax call does not do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/notifications"
    });
```

or

```
$.get('/notifications', function(data) {
  //do something
});
```

Comment: Your first suggestion does not lead the server to redirect the request! Still by specifying `json` as data-type, the returned javascript is invalid (as json) and I cannot execute it through the success callback.